MudBlazor custom css
Why is css not working in MudBlazor?
When I create a server side rendering MudBlazor app from scratch using the Visual Studio MudBlazor project template and I add some custom css styles they wont apply.
The only way to get custom css working is to add them to style attribute.
Is there any way to get this working anyway? Because its getting to its limit if you want to add some more complex css with animations...
CODE
App.razor
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MudBlazorCssTest.styles.css" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

wwwroot/app.css
.test ::deep {
    background-color: red !important;
}

Home.razor
@page "/"

<div class="test">
    <div>This is not red</div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red">
    <div>This is red</div>
</div>


It should be ::deep .test ?  And I see the warning in test:

So if you want to use css globally you could create "App.razor.css"

::deep .test {
    background-color: red !important;
}

For ::deep to work you could wrap the element which has "class" with test using another "<div>".
<div >
    <div class="test">
        <div>This is not red</div>
    </div>
</div>

Test result


This does the trick... Ok I think I get it now: every component need his own xyz.razor.css (I think thats because of the scope?!?). With ::deep it inherits the css to child components. So as App.razor is the root parent, every ::deep is global

Just figured out that !important is not required for it to work and also wrapping the div in another div is not neccessary. You can just put the class directly on the "This is not red"-div
